# Magento 2 rewrite not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, catalogsearch

I need to override this class

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext
Collection
```

in my custom module. I have created `di.xml` in `etc/frontend` folder.

and created the class and overridden the method. This my code:

**di.xml**

```
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="Daiva\Customsearch\Model\Resource\Fulltext\Collection"/>
</config>
```

Class:

```
namespace Daiva\Customsearch\Model\Resource\Fulltext;

/**
 * Fulltext Collection
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
echo "Daiva";
        exit;
        $result = parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
        $this->_totalRecords = null;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

But it is not working. Did i make any mistake?

Comment: Apparently your code is ok, did you try `bin/magento setup:di:compile` ?

Comment: I just cleared the generation folder. I am in developer mode

Comment: Please check below link for reference: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/